# Bar chart grouped by treatment and with subdivided bars in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

How are you? My goal is to create a plot in R that can display 3 distinct variables in a single plot. Let's get to the problem: I have a sample of 2 different environmental soil variables across 3 different treatments and under 2 seasons of the year. But I could not make it.

In this way, I want to generate a figure that displays the treatments on the x-axis and that the bars are divided into subgroups according to each period ('A' and 'B') within each treatment. At the same time, I am interested in having the height of the bars (y-axis) composed of the sum of the 2 analyzed variables, but I want to be able to display the contribution of each variable to the total bar height in different colors Can somebody help me?

[image]

Attached, I provide a figure (reference: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scitotenv.2023.162566) as an example of what I would like to achieve and a reproducible example. Thank you in advance for your support.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
  Season = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
  Treatment = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
  Value1 = c(10, 15, 12, 18.7, 8, 10.94),
  Value2 = c(9.5,13,22.2,02,14,9))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Total.value = (Value1+Value2))
  
  
ggplot(df, aes(x = Treatment, y = Total.value, fill = Season)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  labs(title = 'Grouped Bar Chart with Sub-Groups',
       x = 'Category',
       y = 'Value') +
  theme_bw()
```

I've tried many possibilities, but so far nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. However, can you assist me again? Actually, my interest is not to reproduce a figure exactly like the one I provided as an example, but to generate a graph capable of displaying and grouping the bars and then subdividing the y-axis. My desire is not to use facet_grid() at the moment because I have another variable in my original dataset that I would like to use this function to separate. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are looking for dodged *and* stacked groups, which is difficult in ggplot, though the effect can be achieved using 'sneaky' facets. First, pivot your value columns into long format, then map `fill` to the resulting `name` column. Map `Season` to the x axis but facet by `Treatment`, and remove the gaps between the facet panels:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Value')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Season, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack', color = 'black', linewidth = 0.2, width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(.~Treatment, switch = 'x') +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c('#ffd330', '#93bcbe')) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = 'serif', face = 2),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        axis.line.y = element_line(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A solution that a Brazilian colleague provided me. His name is Fernando. Thank you everyone. Here's the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
      Season = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
      Treatment = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
      Value1 = c(10, 15, 12, 18.7, 8, 10.94),
   Value2 = c(9.5,13,22.2,02,14,9)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(c(Value1, Value2)) |> 
   arrange(Season, Treatment, name) |> 
   group_by(Season, Treatment) |> 
   mutate(value = cumsum(value)) |> 
   mutate(name = factor(name))
    
df2 <- df |> mutate(value = ifelse(name == "Value2", 0, value))
    
ggplot(df) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = Treatment, y = value, group = Season, fill = name),
               data = df |> filter(name == 'Value2'), color = 'black',
               position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
      geom_bar(aes(x = Treatment, y = value, group = Season, fill = name),
               data = df2, color = 'black',
               position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') + 
      labs(title = 'Grouped Bar Chart with Sub-Groups',
           x = 'Category',
           y = 'Value') +
      theme_bw()
```