# How do I plot data for combinations in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| host | pathogen | doses | number of observations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bird | bacteria | 2 | 7 |
| bird | virus | 3 | 4 |
| bird | helminth | 5 | 6 |
| bird | bacteria | 1 | 4 |
| fish | virus | 6 | 8 |
| fish | virus | 7 | 1 |
| fish | bacteria | 8 | 4 |
| mammal | virus | 4 | 2 |

Using ggplot and the stacked barchart, I would like to plot for each host-pathogen combination (on the x-axis), the "number of observations" of doses. So, for example, if the bird-bacteria combination is on the x-axis, on the y-axis I would like it to show that "doses=2" is observed 7 times and "doses=1" is observed 4 times.

Comment: Put pathogen on the x axis, number of observations on the y axis, use "doses" for the fill color and facet by host.

Comment: Is it possible to have all of this on one plot; if I use facet, I get a plot for each combination, but I would like everything on one plot.

Comment: You can easily make facets look like a single plot (what I call "sneaky facets"). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157345/bar-chart-grouped-by-treatment-and-with-subdivided-bars-in-r-with-ggplot2/77157849#77157849) for an example